# How to access to the inner ArrayList<Any> binded by an initial ArrayList of type <Any>

Tags: arrays, list, kotlin, arraylist, dynamic

I am trying to access to the inner ArrayList in Kotlin... Please refer, herein. Is there a way? Many Thanks

```
fun main() {
    
    val y = ArrayList<Any>()
    for (i in 1..2){
        y.add(readln().split(' ').map {
            try {
                it.toInt()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                it
            }
        })
    }
    
    println(y[0]::class.simpleName)
    println(y[1]::class.simpleName)
    println(y)
    y.forEach(::println)
    
}
```

I printed the class for y[0] and y[1] and the binding class y, all are of type ArrayList. However, accessing to the binding ArrayList is possible by way of lamda expression which shall retrieve the inner ArrayList. The inner list isn't accessible. Is there a way to do it?

Any assistance in this regard is appreciated

Comment: Note that in practice, a `List<Any>` is basically never used because it is so impractical to have a list of something and not know what type they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you fill your list `y` only with lists, the simplest way to make the inner lists accessible as `List` would be to provide the type information that `y` is a list of `List`s and not just a list of `Any`s:

```
val y = ArrayList<List<Any>>()
// now you can also iterate over the inner lists
y.forEach { it.forEach(::println) }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for compiler to know that list is actually containing inner lists, since you declared your `ArrayList` as a list of elements of type `Any`.

However, you can make compiler check if list's element is actually an inner list.

```
y.forEach { it ->
    // Note that you cannot check for List<Int> since generic types are erased at runtime
    if (it is List<*>) { 
        println(it)
    }
}
```

The reason it is not possible without explicit check is that `ArrayList<Any>` is not invariant, meaning you cannot guarantee that object of type `Any` will have the functionality required from `List` since any object can be added to `y`.